# How to validate Infinity in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I want to restrict if a variable is infinity.

```
         if(!isNaN(response.MonthlyPayment) && !isFinite(response.MonthlyPayment)){
          //do here
         }
```

Here the infinity is not validating.

Comment: Is your `response.MonthlyPayment` coming as a string value?

Comment: In the bean it is double

Comment: Is that code supposed to be Java or Javascript?  It can't be both!   Please correct the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly check like  this

```
if(!isNaN(response.MonthlyPayment) && response.MonthlyPayment != Infinity) {
    //do here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with this.

> response.MonthlyPayment != Infinity